# HDMI usage gets CPU to %100

Tags: windows-7, cpu, hdmi

I bought a new monitor asus vw266 - when i connect it to my laptop(elitebook 8530w) though hdmi after few minutes of use cpu suddenly jumps to %100 on both cores almost locking the computer rendering it unresponsive..

When I check processes through task manager i do not see any process that is eating up the cpu so I am not able to identify what process is causing this.. But the CPU renains at a constant %100

How do i debug such problem - i could not find much on google..

Note: I had the exact same monitor at a different location connected to this laptop via hdmi without any problems.. I had win 7 32 bit installed at the time though and now i have win 7 64 bit. .not sure if that is making a difference in this particular situation..

Answer (score 0):

Before the cpu spikes, open Resource Monitor (CPU tab), it may show hidden process that are eating CPU cycles.

EDIT: Once open click the CPU tab, then click the cpu column to sort it by highest cpu usage.

All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Resource Monitor

.
[image]

Comment: For spotting the culprit easier, let Resource Monitor sort the table by "CPU" (which is CPU usage). That way, the responsible process will show right on top.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but still very actual. I have the same issue, but not with every HDMI device I connect to.
It looks like there is a temporary solution here:
http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_fix_this_high_cpu_usage_svchost_virus_or_whatever_it_is.html
Did you tried to stop **windows update process**?

Comment: That link has nothing to do with the question.  It is about high CPU usage in Windows XP related to the automatic update service.  It was fixed by an update in 2007, as described in your link.